# Iterations in Stylus

Tags: css, stylus

I have Stylus file which looks like:

```
div.c0
   background-color $background-color0
   color $color-0

div.c2
   background-color $background-color2
   color $color-2

div.c4
   background-color $background-color4
   color $color-4

div.c8
   background-color $background-color8
   color $color-8

div.c16
   background-color $background-color16
   color $color-16
```

Can I use Stylus iterations here to simplify my Stylus file ?

Comment: I can't test it so i post comment :       `for num in 0 2 4 8 16`
        `div.num`
            `background-color $background-colornum`
            `color $color-num` [source](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/iteration.html)

Comment: I need somthing like div.c'num', not div.num

Comment: And even div.num throw error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no interpolation (yet) for variables, you can use `lookup` bif to get the values of such variables. So, for you case, the code would be this:

```
for $i in 0..4
  $num = $i ? 1 : 0
  $num = $num * 2 for $j in 0..($i - 1)
  div.c{$num}
    background-color: lookup('$background-color' + $num)
    color: lookup('$color' + $num)
```